# Found with Wooded kingdom art

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

I have started a new game in Super Mario Odyssey, but a moon is giving me trouble. I seem to have all of the main game Steam Gardens moons except one. Going to the marker on my map takes me to an image showing the koopa from the trace walking game, a compass pointing north and a blue cross next to two or 3 dried bushes.

I have gone to the sand kingdom to try finding where the blue cross would be and ground pounding there. I have tried ground pounding at both the nearest set of bushes to the koopa and the set I got to when walking north from the koopa *(which were by the poison lake)*. Nothing seems to be happening. I tried again with the trace walking game active, but nothing still seems to be happening. *(The trace game ends before I can get to the bushes in the north.)*

Am I missing something? Have I just not found the right spot, or is there something else I need to do at that spot? Also, any tips for kingdom art power moons in general? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From IGN's ["Hint Art Locations and Solutions" guide](https://www.ign.com/wikis/super-mario-odyssey/Hint_Art_Locations_and_Solutions#Wooded_Kingdom_Hint_Art):

> The art shows a Red Koopa in a sombrero, and directs you to head North of him and find two bushes. This Red Koopa is none other than the proprieter of the Walking Game in Sand Kingdom. Fly back to the Sand Kingdom and head north, past the large sinkhole, and find the two bushes at the far end of the map (Quadrant A4).
>
> [image]
>   [image]
>
> Ground pound on the two bushes to unearth the hidden Power Moon.
>
> [image]